# How do you add the number of values on a histogram and the percentages?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python function that lets me plot a histogram. On each part of the bars, I display the number of values. Then I display the percentages of each part of the bars. However, it's impossible to align the number of values and the percentages in order to have annotations like this for example: "3243 (46%)". How do I proceed? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    result = duckdb.sql(q).df()
    result = result.pivot(index='Population', columns='sexe', values='nbre_sexe')

    ax = result.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=['blue', 'red'], figsize=(12, 8))
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1), loc="upper left")
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)

    for container in ax.containers:
        ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%d', label_type='center', color='white', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')

    totals = result.sum(axis=1)
    for p in ax.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height() / totals[int(p.get_x())])
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
        y = p.get_height()
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y), ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold', xytext=(0, 5), textcoords='offset points')

    plt.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-', alpha=0.3)

    plt.show()
```

Here's an example of what I get:

[image: Here's an example of what I get]

I'm expecting annotations like that : "3243 (46%)", in the middle of each parts of bars.